# iOS combine Publishers.Just deprecated

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

In a operator chain like this you used to be able to return Publishers.Just(defaultValue) but it is deprecated and I can't find a way to do this functionality anymore. What is the new way to return a defaultValue?

```
 $query
    .throttle(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, latest: true)
    .removeDuplicates()
    .map { query -> AnyPublisher<[Repo], Never> in
       guard query.count >= 3 else {
          return Publishers.Just([])
                   .eraseToAnyPublisher()
          }
          return API().search(with: query)
               .retry(3)
               .eraseToAnyPublisher()
          }
```

Comment: When was it deprecated? It still shows up in the [current online docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just).

Comment: The one that @NRitH posted is not under the `Publishers` namespace. Try dropping `Publishers.`

Comment: Good point. That suggests a compilation failure, not just a deprecation warning.

Comment: Just is it's own type but it it doesn't help me guard out of this function without changing the return type of AnyPublisher<[Repo], Never>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this to work:

```
Result.Publisher([])
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

If you need to send back just an error, you'll likely need to specify the type as well:

```
Result<YourObject, YourError>.Publisher(.failure(YourError.error))
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/publisher)